# Neo4jError: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: variable not defined but it is defined

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm getting the `Neo4jError: Failed to invoke procedure 'apoc.do.when': Caused by: org.neo4j.exceptions.SyntaxException: Variable 'item' not defined (line 1, column 24 (offset: 23)) "match (pr:Product {id: item.id})"` in the `ifQuery` when I use the `apoc.do.when()` procedure .
Why is the `apocalypse.do.when()` `ifQuery` not getting access to `item` parameter while the `condition` does?

```
`
with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as order
create (o:Order) set o = order
with o, apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($request) as request
merge (u:User {uid: o.customerId})
merge (s:Shop {uid: o.shopId})
create (u)-[rel:MADE_ORDER]->(o)<-[rel1:RECEIVED_ORDER]-(s)
with o, u, s, request
unwind o.cart as jsonItems
with o, u, s, request, apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(jsonItems) as item
    
CALL apoc.do.when(
item.isPromotion = false,

'match (pr:Product {id: item.id}) 
set pr.soldQuantity = pr.soldQuantity + 1, 
pr.availableQuantity = pr.availableQuantity -1
create(u)-[:BOUGHT]->(pr)<-[:CONTAINS]-(o)
',

'match (p:Promotion {id: item.id})
set p.soldQuantity = pr.soldQuantity + 1, 
pr.availableQuantity = p.availableQuantity -1 
create(u)-[:BOUGHT]->(p)<-[:CONTAINS]-(o)'

,{})
YIELD value
return o as savedOrder
`
```

`item` is decoded from an array of json string `cart`. Just to make sure I wasn't mistaking in decoding it with the `apocalypse.convert.fromJsonMap()` procedure I did a test and created an `Item` node for each element and it works just fine.. the node gets created with all its parameters.  Just as a test I passed the variables to be used in the `ifQuery`and `elseQuery` adding `with o, u, s, request, item`  to them but then it just throws the error on the first variable `o` ..

```
`
with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as order
create (o:Order) set o = order
with o, apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($request) as request
merge (u:User {uid: o.customerId})
merge (s:Shop {uid: o.shopId})
create (u)-[rel:MADE_ORDER]->(o)<-[rel1:RECEIVED_ORDER]-(s)
with o, u, s, request
unwind o.cart as jsonItems
with o, u, s, request, apoc.convert.fromJsonMap(jsonItems) as item
create (i: Item) set i = item
return o as savedOrder
`
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong with the `apocalypse.do.when()` procedure?

As always many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem being I wasn't passing the variables to the procedure..

```
,{})
```

so I changed it to

```
,{
  item: item,
  o: o,
  u: u,
  s: s
      })
```

and it works as expected.